# Machine/compiler dependent segfault with c code

Tags: c, linux, macos, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run a parallel code (numerical simulation) on a Linux machine. I have tested the code configuration on my laptop (OSX) and all works fine. When I ship to the larger (Linux) machine it segfaults on the first timestep.

I didn't write the code and don't want to get into debugging it. I am hoping that it may be possible to solve the problem with a different compiler or flags.

On my laptop (OSX) I have the code running with the default compiler.

```
cc --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
```

On the Linux machine that I work on, I am using

```
cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4
```

I have tried both 4.9.4 and 4.8.4 on the Linux machine, and both give the same segfault.

My `Makefile` sets the following directives:

```
CFLAGS = -O3
LDFLAGS = -I`pwd` -I$(SRCDIR) -I/usr/bin/include -I/usr/include/mpi
LIBFLAGS = -lm -lnetcdf -lmpi -L/usr/bin/lib
```

I know this is a shot in the dark, but if anyone has a suggestion for a change I could try to get this working on the linux machine I would be most grateful. In case it's not obvious to you already, I am a mere regular scientist, not a computer scientist, so most of this is black magic to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hoping that changing the compiler flags will help is not a well-known strategy for solving problems like this. I would suggest you try adding debugging flags to your Makefile and spend 30 minutes learning a deugger.

Comment: You're going to have to debug the problem. You've probably got undefined behaviour in the code and different systems react differently, and both are correct because the required behaviour is undefined.   There's a moderate chance that you're using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: "I didn't write the code and don't want to get into debugging it." Sorry, that's your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't write the code and don't want to get into debugging it.

Well, if you refuse to help yourself, you'll have to bribe someone else to do it for you.

> I am hoping that it may be possible to solve the problem with a different compiler or flags.

It may well be possible, but finding the right flags *requires* understanding the problem in the first place.

Otherwise, you are trying to [program by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence), and that rarely leads to success.